# Is there a way to specify a Ramp-up time (like in JMeter) for TestNG multithreaded tests?

Tags: multithreading, testing, jmeter, testng

I'm testing an api with testNG and I'd like to know if it's possible to specify a ramp-up time for multithreaded tests.
What would be the easiest way to do so?

e.g. JMeter has the possibility to set: Start X threads in Y seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, TestNG creates the thread pools at initialization time.

You might want to roll your own executor test logic for this.